# PHP- MySQL Database insert action not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

My php code that insert `$_POST` into database doesn't work.

> The error = Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '). The $sql is also
>   correct..

The Connection with Database is fine. 
What am I doing wrong

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['knop'])){
    if(){
        //IN DB STEKEN
        $sql = "INSERT INTO workstations_nl (workstation_name, workstation_user, teamviewer_id, unattended_access, suezbox_id, function) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $waardes = array($_POST['name'],$_POST['user'],$_POST['teamviewer'],$_POST['unattended_access'],$_POST['suezbox'],$_POST['function']);
        Db::execute($sql,$waardes);
        header('Location: workstations_nl.php?msg=insertok');
        exit();      
    }
}else{
    header('Location: insert_workstations_nl.php?msg=insertnietok');    
}
?>
```

**The HTML**

```
<form id="formulier" name="formulier" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <table width="90%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>User: *</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="user" name="user">
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Workstation: *</td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="name" name="name" placeholder="" style="width: 50%;"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Teamviewer: *</td>
            <td><textarea id="teamviewer" name="teamviewer" placeholder="" style="width: 50%;"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unattended Acces: *</td>
            <td><textarea id="unattended_acces" name="unattended_acces"  style="width: 50%;"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suezbox: *</td>
            <td><textarea id="suezbox" name="suezbox"  style="width: 50%;"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" id="knop" name="knop" value="Add New Suezbox">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: "if(){" does not look right .. which line is the parse error at ?

Comment: "?,?,?,?,?,?,?" you have 6 fields but seven "?" that will probably not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line with proper line:

```
if(){
```

There is no condition added in `if`.

It will always return NULL and your query will never be executed.

Your SQL has six fields and you are binding 7 values.

That is mismatch.

Correct SQL to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO workstations_nl (workstation_name, 
workstation_user, teamviewer_id, unattended_access, suezbox_id, 
function) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 
// Observe the question marks. One is removed.
```

Comment: addapted, but the code still not works..

Comment: print the sql and paste in the question.

Comment: Wich sql doe you mean?

Comment: `Insert` sql. Paste it.

Comment: The code works. Thanks!

Comment: @GielEvens, you are welcome.